# Can I use this code with Filezilla?

Tags: c#

Can I use this code with Filezilla?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does Filezilla need to be installed on the same computer my program is running on for this code to work?

My program creates files periodically and saves them to a folder on the computer it's installed on. I want these files to be periodically uploaded to a server of some sort. (Please let me know if you have any recommendations for this besides FTP.)

I need the whole of my program to be virtually invisible so that anyone using the computer can't see it. Does this work with Filezilla?

If I can use this code with Filezilla, how do I do so? What is the specific data for Filezilla? I know the code states what I need, but I need it to be specific for Filezilla if that makes sense.

PS I'm using Virtual Studio Community 2015.

[*Code credit*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: FileZilla is an FTP client, this code replicates a fraction of what FileZilla does by uploading files using the FTP protocol. It does not rely on FileZilla at all. Unfortunately the rest of your question is confusing to me.

Comment: @Equalsk Is there another client or whatever that will do what I'm asking better than Filezilla? My program creates PNG files periodically and saves them to a folder on the computer it's installed on. I want these files to be periodically uploaded to a server of some sort so that they are accessible from another computer or device if that makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand what FileZilla has to do with anything, it's just one of many FTP programs. This code will upload a file to an FTP server if used correctly. If you don't know how to do that then nobody here can teach you, you'd need to learn it yourself or hire a programmer.

Comment: FileZilla came into play as just an example. It's the only free FTP program I know of.

Answer (score 0):

For saving a text file on a remote server, you do not necessarily need FileZilla. In your C# program you can directly save the generated files on the server you want:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath + fileName, yourTextFile);
```

You only need to share the destination folder (on the remote server) with the user executing the code. You can also add a task (in task scheduler) copying the generated files to the remote server using a simple script ([Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx)).

Comment: They're .PNG files actually. And I want to make them accessable on another device besides the one the program is installed.
What "server" are you talking about?

Comment: What is this another device?

Comment: My brain must've just short circuited with that last comment. Sorry about that.

I meant that the files my program is creating and saving are PNG files. Will this still work with those type of files? I just want to make the PNG files accessible from another device (ie. computer). That's why I originally was going to try and have them automatically upload to a cloud like Google Drive, but I found the API and all way too difficult for my level of coding knowledge.

Comment: The other device can be a computer or a phone. I want to be able to see a list of all the PNG files my program has created from the computer it is installed on, but I want to be able to see them and open them on another computer.